# Python - string.split() but ignore single spaces (e.g. between words)

Tags: python, list, split, whitespace

The idea is the following:

```
string = 'ABC DEF  GHI JK    LMNO P'

list = string.split()

print(list)
```

Output:

```
ABC DEF
GHI JK
LMNO P
```

Obviously that doesn't quite work. Is there a trick with `.split` to ignore single spaces when splitting a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of problem where regular expressions excel. So let's construct a regex to find all the spaces, that have more than one space character. `\s` matches spaces, so let's go with that:

```
\s
```

And to match N-or-more than something in regex, you put a `{N,}` after the expression. So, let's put `{2,}` in to match for 2-or-more:

```
\s{2,}
```

Now that we have our regular expression, we need a regular expression parser. Python comes with one built in. Python's regex module *also* comes with a function that will split every time the regular expression pings on a match. So, we do:

```
import re # This is the built-in regex module
string = "ABC DEF  GHI JK    LMNO P"
my_list = re.split("\s{2,}", string)
```

Unrelated to this question, note how I changed your variable from `list` to `my_list`. This is because `list` is a built-in keyword in Python, that you don't want to over-write.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to split by two or more spaces:

```
import re
re.split("\s{2,}", string)
#['ABC DEF', 'GHI JK', 'LMNO P']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using regex then you can just split on spaces like you were doing and filter the results. Like so:

```
astring = 'ABC DEF  GHI JK    LMNO P'

def strip_spaces(astring):
    temp = astring.split(" ")
    return [element for element in temp if len(element) != 0]

    print(strip_spaces(astring))

# Output: ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JK', 'LMNO', 'P']
```